# Flutter project, some filenames not identified as .dart files in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, naming

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oswWg.png)

I already tried to modify the type analysis of android studio, restarted and recreated the project.

I reinstalled Android Studio and tried different Flutter SDKs and Android Studio versions, but I cannot work with .dart files named "login_event.dart"  and "auth_service.dart", because Android Studio isn't recognizing them as .dart (no linting, just plain text, as you can see on the icon type in the picture).

I have over 40 other dart files in the project which all are working fine.
Just these two specific names can't be identified.
Even if the compilation of these to files is working, is is still annoying not to have advantages of normal dart files while coding.

Why this error occurs only exclusively with this naming, globally on my system regardless of AndroidStudio version and project is very incomprehensible to me.
It looks like Android Studio just doesn't want to recognize some names.

Comment: Did you try to create new recognized Dart files and to copy the content of your strange files into the new ones ?

Comment: Yes the dart code is then recognized (in a file with another name), I just do not understand why I can't name dart files like I want them to be named

Comment: I have to admit that I don't know either, maybe something in the cache. Did you try to call flutter clean or to invalidate it using File > Invalidates Cache / Restart... ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  An abstract class that extended another class caused the .dart files that extended the abstract class to lose their syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

call flutter clean or to invalidate it using File > Invalidates Cache / Restart... ? solved the problem